# MediaController with MediaPlayer in Service getDuration error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my app I have an audio player `Activity` which simply shows the current song title and album cover art together with a `MediaController`. I also have a `Service` which implements `MediaController.MediaPlayerControl` and which uses a `MediaPlayer` for playback.

In general everything works fine - the `Activity` binds to the `Service` and sets the `MediaController` to control the `MediaPlayer`.

The problem comes when starting a new song but *ONLY* when the `MediaController` is shown on the screen. If it is hidden or even if I leave the `Activity` using BACK and return to the home screen, the 'playlist' is processed without a problem. If the `MediaContoller` is visible, however, the player dies silently and the seek / progress bar shows a start and end time of 466:36:07 and logcat shows...

```
attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
```

I don't get an unhandled exception stacktrace in logcat - just that message and `MediaPlayer` simply stops playing. I've Googled for the error and get nearly 3000 hits (most of which are for questions here on SO) but I can't find a situation which matches mine.

Relevant `Activity` code...

```
public class AudioPlayerActivity extends Activity
    implements OnKeyListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_player);

        // Find views here

        controller = new MyMediaController(this);
        controller.setAnchorView(ll);
        controller.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mBound = bindService(new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        try {
            getCurrentItem();
            mediaFilename = currentItem.getTrackName();
            coverArtPath = currentItem.getMediaArtUrl();
            updateTrackDetails();
            Intent playerServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class);
            startService(playerServiceIntent);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showMediaController() {
        // Called by onTouchEvent(...)` when the screen is touched
        if (mBound) {
            controller.setMediaPlayer(mService);
            controller.setEnabled(true);
            controller.show(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Service` has the following code...

```
public class NDroidTEMusicPlayerService extends Service
    implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,
        MediaPlayerControl {

    private void setupMediaPlayer() {
        ...
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(trackUrl);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stop();
        mp.reset();
        currentItem = playList.getNextItem(isRepeating);
        Intent i = new Intent(MYAPP.ACTION_MYAPP_UPDATE_PLAY_VIEW);
        i.putExtra("current_item", currentItem);
        sendBroadcast(i);
        setupMediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        int duration = 0;
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) 
            duration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        return duration;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to instantiate a new MyMediaController every time the screen is touched?

Comment: @leandrocastelli : No. That method was originally only called once which is why I created it there. Since posting this question I've now moved that to the `onCreate` method and edited my question. It doesn't make any difference to my problem though.